# Android Studio 2.3: Autogenerated Debug-APK no longer runs on physical device

Tags: android, apk, android-studio-2.3

I used to test my Android apps (min API 21, target 25) in an API 21 AVD. After clicking the "run app" button in Android Studio, a debug APK was built in {project}/app/build/outputs/apk/. I then copied that APK to my physical API 25 device for further testing.

Since upgrading Android Studio from 2.2.3.0.145.3537739 to 2.3.0.8.162.3764568 on Gentoo Linux, those autogenerated APKs no longer run on the physical device. The apps crash instantly upon startup and the log shows a "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity" caused by a "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class {my main activity class}".

When I build a debug APK manually by clicking on "Build > Build APK", the generated APK has a different file size than the autogenerated one, plus it runs on the physical device without any complaints.

So, there are actually two questions:
1. Why does the manually generated debug APK differ from the autogenerated one?
2. What is causing the autogenerated one to fail on my physical device since Android Studio 2.3? It worked fine with all Studio versions before.

Hoping for some insight, even though USB debugging exists and the process of copying the debug APK to the device is actually pretty pointless. :-)

Comment: Any chance you upgraded the android gradle plugin as well? Or the sdk tools maybe?

Comment: That's possible, I don't really know which recent update is actually responsible for the new behaviour.
Current Gradle plugin is 2.3.0 (2.2.3 before) and Gradle is 3.3 (seemed to be 2.14.1 before). Android SDK Tools 25.2.5, Android SDK Platform-tools 25.0.5, Android SDK Build-tools 25.0.2 (with 25.0.3 available but not suggested for updating in SDK manager, why that?).

Comment: Any chance your using the instant run in Android Studio? Try disabling it from settings and see if the problem still exists

Comment: Jackpot. After disabling instant run, the APK is now the same size as the manually generated one, and it works in both the API 21 AVD and the API 25 physical device. The documentation at https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html even mentions in "Limitations of Instant Run" > "Deploying to multiple devices" that the instant run APKs use API specific code, so it might just have been wild luck that those API 21 APKs previously ran fine on the API 25 device. My workflow was pointless anyway, but now the "bug" actually makes sense. Thank you so very much, ahasbini!

Comment: Sure anytime. I'll post an answer if you're ok with that

Comment: Go ahead... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a recap of the comments to the question, if Instant Run is enabled then generated debug apk will contain device API specific code hence rendering it not usable on other APIs that it was not built for. Turning off the Instant Run would solve that.